# Subqueries for aggregation needs in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate

I have a table like this:

```
Id    Date     Price  Item  Type
1  2009-09-21    25     1     M
2  2009-08-31    16     2     T
1  2009-09-23    21     1     M
2  2009-09-03    12     3     T
```

I try to receive the output of ID and column of sum price mult items for type='M' and another column with same logic for type='T'

Only way how to do it for me is using multi-cte but it is kind of complex and big:

```
with cte as (
select distinct a.id, a.date
sum(price*a.item) as numm
from table a
where a.type='M'
group by a.id), 

crx as (
select cte.id, cte.numm, sum(a.price*a.item) as numm_1  from cte
join table a on a.id=cte.id and a.date=cte.date
where a.type='T'
group by cte.id)

select * from crx
```

Having a certain feeling that it can be done better (for example using subqueries)-asking you how can it be done.

p.s.

SQLlite stuff would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,Date date,Price money,Item int,Type varchar(25))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'2009-09-21',25,1,'M'),
(2,'2009-08-31',16,2,'T'),
(1,'2009-09-23',21,1,'M'),
(2,'2009-09-03',12,3,'T')

Select ID
      ,sum(case when Type='M' then Price*Item else 0 end) as M
      ,sum(case when Type='T' then Price*Item else 0 end) as T
 From  YourTable
 Group By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  M       T
1   46.00   0.00
2   0.00    68.00
```